# Database-aware Rails Migration

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-migrations

I am working on a rails application, and I am using Sqlite in my dev environment and PostgreSQL in production. Is there any way to write a "database-aware" migration? i.e. one that would `execute` a certain SQL statement on Sqlite and a differetn statement on Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to write something like:

```
class MyMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.kind_of? ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter
      execute 'SQL Statement...'
    else
      execute 'Different SQL Statement...'
    end
  end

  def down
    ...
  end
end
```

Its not something I have had to implement myself so I'm not aware of any pitfalls.